# "inexplicable" maven return status code: what can cause maven to return 1?

Tags: maven

We have maven build, which just build multi-module project, nothing fancy I'd think. It builds, finishing with green saying SUCCESSFUL, artifacts are deployed. No test failing, no error log. Nothing. With --debug there is nothing suspicious. Everything is fine. Except return code. Maven sometimes return 1 instead of zero. It happens also with only `mvn clean install`

I have literally no leads what can cause that. Any hints? Or ideas what I could check.

edit: how about some leaks for example? Could it be possible, if there are some threads started by integrtion testing still running, that maven would just kill them 'somehow' and mark build as unsuccessful? We have one dependency, which behaves suspicioustly to say at least, which could do that in principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so having no better answer, I'll post here my "hunch".

Our maven returned 1 in about 50% of invocations, no idea why. Even if our app build, tests passed, and app was deployed to repository and working on production. Having no better information, I tried to wipe out one problematic dependency from integration tests. Now we have 0 returned from maven as expected in 100% of cases. So I'm guessing, that this dependency did not shutdown itself properly, spring/maven had to do something about it, and status code 1 relates to failed cleanup after build, not build itself.